# How a high Earth to Neutral voltage affects electronic equipment like L2 or L3 switches?

Tags: voltage, earth, neutral

We have lot of communication equipment installed recently in our organisation. From then, lot of pressure on us to reduce Earth to Neutral voltage at the input of our communication equipment like L2 or L3 switches which are frequently failing due to high ENV. Can anyone explain how it really affects the equipment performance, please?

Comment: We don't know what equipment you have so how can we answer how it affects your equipment?

Comment: These are L3 and L2 switches(communication equipment) as I mentioned in the title of the question. L2 switches are getting unserviceable due to high ENV. To reduce ENV, we installed Isolation transformers. But, I did not know how that ENV eg. 5V really affects the L2 switch.

Comment: L3 and L2 switches for what? And do these switches have a name and model, or manual that says under what voltages it works? Besides, how would neutral to earth voltage affect the equipment performance? And what performance? Do you think it somehow has more packet loss, ping time, or bit errors due to neutral to earth voltage?

Comment: @Justme It's probably because folks using the communication equipment (phone system?) are getting shocked. But it may be related to how these communication devices are connected to each other, too. Anyway, to meet very stringent requirements, it's normal to install dedicated transformers at the load. Another possibility is to run large guage wiring to reduce the return drop. But none of us can hope to explain how it "really affects" the equipment without knowing equipment details.

Comment: We are using L2 & L3 equipment made by Cisco for fibre optic communication within the organisation. Our organisation issued standard values. For ex: At L2 switch input supply (230VAC, Single Phase, 50Hz) , the ENV should be less than 2V and for L3 it should be less than 1V.

Answer (score 1):

5V earth to neutral voltage is perfectly normal under certain conditions (for example a long run of single ended single phase wiring) and should not be a problem for any competently designed equipment. Heck many countries have reversible plugs, so there is a 50% chance that the "neutral" connection of the equipment will actually end up being connected to the live conductor. Equipment standards take this into account.

Generally in electronic equipment the mains goes almost immediately into a bridge rectifier that does not treat live any different from neutral.

Whatever is killing your communications equipment I can confidently state that 5 volts or so between earth and neutral is not it.

What would be a much bigger problem is if you have a three phase (or split phase) system with a high-impedance neutral. If the load is well-balanced it could well be that the earth to neutral voltage is normally fairly low, but that switching transients lead to brief excursions to much higher voltages. 400V into a peice of 230V equipment, even briefly, could very well do damage.

It may be that the field techs have picked up on the neutral to earth voltage, not because it's a problem in itself, but because (in a 3 phase with neutral or split phase system) it is a symptom of a high-impedance neutral.